# Unity3d - Raycast doesnt Count Hit when multiple Colliers are in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

```
private bool InteractCombat() {
  GameObject target;
  RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(GetMouseRay());
  foreach(RaycastHit hit in hits) {
    if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "gameEnemy") {
      target = hit.transform.gameObject;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    if (target == null) return false;
    if (target != null) {
      targetToAttack = target;
      targetState = targetToAttack.GetComponent < GameObjectState > ();
    };
    if (!targetState.IsDead || targetState.CanBeDestroyed) {
      GetComponent < CursorChanger > ().setCursorToAttack();
      enableHealthBarAndAdjustSize();
      if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        GetComponent < Animator > ().ResetTrigger("stopattack");
        GetComponent < Attacker > ().Attack(targetToAttack);
      }
    } else {
      disableEnemyInfo();
      GetComponent < CursorChanger > ().setCursorToWalk();
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is basicly the Code from my PlayerController script.

With one Enemy in the Scene, with one Collider everything works fine.

When i add a second clone of the Enemy Prefab, the Raycast method here cannot find the GameObject - when i remove the Capsule Collider of one of the Clones, everything is fine with killing the Remaining Enemy, who still has its Collider.

What am i missing here ? why cant i have multiple Colliders in the Scene (Even on different Objects) without breaking my whole attack functionality??.

Comment: Paste the code with proper indents

Comment: Ir doesnt Work As i want :/

Comment: there are online code beautifiers, I just used one

Comment: Well, you always `return` at some point on the first item of `hits`, so only the first hit is ever relevant.

Comment: You return `true` for each item in hits that is not tagged `gameEnemy` .. Note btw that you should rather use `CompareTag` instead of a direct `==` .. also there are some redundant checks like `if(target == null)` and then `if(target != null)` and in general you should rather only check `if(target)` for types of `UnityEngine.Object` ..

Comment: @derHugo yes i followed a Tutorial and he did a Lot of quick exits Like  if (target==null) Return false;. I didnt refactor remains of it. When a gameobject with "gameEnemy" Tag is found in Hits, this gameobject ist filled in target.    Problem is, As soon As 2 enemys fromm the Same prefab are präsent in the Scene, my Raycast Method only find's the Terrain , nothing Else. With one enemy and so one Collider everything works fine. When i remove the Collider from one of the enemys, the Other one is attackable again...   Confused

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(RaycastHit hit in hits) {
if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "gameEnemy") {
  target = hit.transform.gameObject;
} else {
  return false; //Had to be changed to Continue, to not return the function, to try 
                  next element
}
if (target == null) return false;
if (target != null) {
  targetToAttack = target;
  targetState = targetToAttack.GetComponent < GameObjectState > ();
};
if (!targetState.IsDead || targetState.CanBeDestroyed) {
  GetComponent < CursorChanger > ().setCursorToAttack();
  enableHealthBarAndAdjustSize();
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
    GetComponent < Animator > ().ResetTrigger("stopattack");
    GetComponent < Attacker > ().Attack(targetToAttack);
  }
}
```

The problem was i mistook "return false" with
"continue". this way only the first element ever was checked, and this way always terrain.
Stupid mistake, but took me forever to figure it out, thanks to the Answers of @Ruzhim and @derHugo